# Scrapy, Parse items data from page then follow link to get additional items data

Tags: python, callback, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a problem to scrape additional fields which are on other pages after scraped data from first page e.g:

Here is my code:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from IMDB_Frompage.items import ImdbFrompageItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

URL = "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=100&ref_=nv_ch_mm_1&start=1&title_type=feature,tv_series,tv_movie"

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "imdb"
    allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]
    start_urls = [URL]
    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.5

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('100&ref'), restrict_xpaths=('//span[@class="pagination"]/a[contains(text(),"Next")]')), callback='parse_page', follow=True),)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = ImdbFrompageItem()
        links = hxs.select("//td[@class='title']")
        items=[]
        for link in links:
            item = ImdbFrompageItem()
            item['link'] = link.select("a/@href").extract()[0]
            item['new_link'] ='http://www.imdb.com'+item['link']
            new_links = ''.join(item['new_link'])
            request = Request(new_links, callback=self.parsepage2)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request
            yield item

    def parsepage2(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        blocks = hxs.select("//td[@id='overview-top']")
        for block in blocks:
            item = ImdbFrompageItem()
            item["title"] = block.select("h1[@class='header']/span[@itemprop='name']/text()").extract()
            item["year"] = block.select("h1[@class='header']/span[@class='nobr']").extract()
            item["description"] = block.select("p[@itemprop='description']/text()").extract()
            yield item
```

Part of results is:

```
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"link": , "new_link": }
....
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"title": , "description":}
{"title": , "description":}
next page
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"title": , "description":}
```

My results don't contain all data ({"title": , "description":}) for each link

But I want something like that:

```
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"title": , "description":}
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"title": , "description":}
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"title": , "description":}
{"link": , "new_link": }
....
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"title": , "description":}
next page
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"title": , "description":}
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"title": , "description":}
{"link": , "new_link": }
{"title": , "description":}
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: One guess is to check exactly the behavior of the yield. The first time the for calls the generator object created from your function, it will run the code in your function from the beginning until it hits yield, then it'll return the first value of the loop. Then, each other call will run the loop you have written in the function one more time, and return the next value, until there is no value to return.So first the function analyze all the links in the loop after it start with the new links.  more details here stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python

Comment: Problems are:
1. Scraped data from links (`{"title": , "description":}`) are not together with this link (`{"link": , "new_link": }`) (I resolved this issue after @JimmyZhang response)
2. Why parser follows not to all links on the first page and select links for scraping by randomly. e.g In page 100 links results: `link1 data; link12 data link36 data ... then follows to next page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy can't ensure that all request parsing in order, it is **unordered**.

The execution sequence may be like that :

1. call parse1();
2. call parse1();
3. call parse1();
4. call parse2();
5. ....

Maybe you can change your code like that to get what you want:

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    links = hxs.select("//td[@class='title']")
    for link in links:
        new_links = ''.join('http://www.imdb.com'+item['link'])
        request = Request(new_links, callback=self.parsepage2)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        request.meta['link'] = link.select("a/@href").extract()[0]
        request.meta['new_link'] = new_links
        yield request


def parsepage2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    blocks = hxs.select("//td[@id='overview-top']")
    for block in blocks:
        item = ImdbFrompageItem()
        item["link"] = response["link"]
        item["new_link" = response["new_link"]
        item["title"] = block.select("h1[@class='header']/span[@itemprop='name']/text()").extract()
        item["year"] = block.select("h1[@class='header']/span[@class='nobr']").extract()
        item["description"] = block.select("p[@itemprop='description']/text()").extract()

        yield item
```

So you will get result like that:

```
{"link": , "new_link": ,"title": , "description":}
```

I am not sure that my code can run directly, I just give an inspire for you to realize what you want.

Comment: Thanks  @JimmyZhang for response it's really helpful, I edited my code and now it works fine my results is:
`{"link": , "new_link": ,"title": , "description":}`
but I still don't understand why parser not follows to all links on the first page and select links for scraping by randomly.
e.g
In page 100 links
results:
`link1 data;
link12 data
link36data
...`
then follows to next page

Maybe you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think the all links in one page, are parsed one by one, can you give some detail information; accept the answer if it helped you.